# Error message importing MHX2 in 2.8

Tags: add-on, import, error

I'm definitely an amateur so excuse me if this is an obvious thing, but I'm trying to import Make Human characters into blender to fix clothing layer issues before moving them into Unity. I'm more than open to alternative suggestions on this whole process but I'll describe what I'm doing and what's going on right now.

I made a character in Make Human and exported them as an MHX2 file. I then installed the MHX2 importer from this URL https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange

This allowed me to see MHX2 files to import. But when I selected my imported NPC I get a redline of error messages and it fails to upload. After mashing my keyboard I managed to get this window pop up somehow, which I assume is the error log: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/353422958984953857/627373902674395136/unknown.png

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? My one and only thing that I need to do is fix clothing layering on Make Human NPCs, if there's a simpler way of doing that with a different program or something obvious I'm missing with this one then I'd really appreciate a hand. Whether or not you've got a suggestion, thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add-on hasn't been properly updated for Blender 2.80. It tries to access `color_space` on an *Image Texture* node, which is no longer part of [`ShaderNodeTexImage`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.html) in Blender 2.80. [It used to be in Blender 2.79b and before](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.html?highlight=color_space).

The proper way of accessing the color space settings is to retrieve the [`Image`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#colorspace_settings) object referenced by `ShaderNodeTexImage` which has the [`colorspace_settings`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#colorspace_settings).

[The issue has already been reported to the developer.](https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/issues/73/traceback-error-cannot-import-makehuman)

Comment: Not meaning to sound dense but there's a lot of terminology in there that I'm not familiar with. Would reverting to 2.79b fix this issue as you described it?

Comment: @WilliamG Yes, but then you need to use the 2.79b compatible version of the add-on as well.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: @WilliamG You're welcome! If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Will do, thank you.